# Como ordenar los datos de una variable basada en un SDT de varios niveles

Tags: genexus

Tengo un procedure que devuelve un SDT que tiene una estructura de varios niveles(corresponde a un JSON de respuesta a un POST).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
&ConsultaMenuesDist_OUT.FromJson(&httpclient01.ToString())
```

La variable `&ConsultaMenuesDist_OUT` que es del tipo SDT, se genera perfecto
y puedo visualizar su contenido en un Grid sobre un PanelSD.

Ahora necesito ordenar el contenido de la variable antes de mostrarla.
Pero no consigo cómo escribir la instrucción de ordenamiento correctamente para
conseguir ordenar descendentemente los datos por el campo `z_INT01_33`

```
&pConsultaMenuesDist_OUT.fs_P5500004_W5500004B.data.gridData.rowset.Sort(["????"])
```

Se puede ordenar este tipo de variable basada en un SDT de varios subniveles ? cómo debería  escribir la instruccion para este caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ordenar la variable basada en un SDT con varios niveles,  hay que ir bajando hasta llegar al nodo que es Coleccion (en este caso "rowset") luego llamar al metodo Sort y pasarle entre comilladas dobles el nombre del elemento por el cual necesitamos ordenar. Si se lo encierra entre corchetes lo ordena descendentemente. Por ej:

> 

&pConsultaMenuesDist_OUT.fs_P5500004_W5500004B.data.gridData.rowset.Sort("[z_INT01_33.value]")

> 